# Eclipse PDT PHP + HTML Formatter is not aligned?

Tags: php, html, eclipse, formatting, eclipse-pdt

[image]

In Eclipse(PDT) PHP->Code Style->Formatter i use a format like [this](http://pastebin.com/M4pzHLsu)

So **how can i align php + html code together better than the picture above?**

Answer (score 0):

In general should be aligned (especially in PDT 3.4). But this might be a bug like : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=466913

Please report your problem on PDT bugzilla : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=PDT

Comment: when i use if else cause and html together, its not align correctly. I reported it as a bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=469490

Comment: Thank you. PDT 3.5 will be released shortly, so probably we will not be able to fix that, but in 3.6 it's possible.